# Can't see my state updated if i console.log outside the axios .then function

Tags: reactjs, axios

i'm trying to get my hands dirty with Api and Axios calls inside React. I am having this issue. Inside the componentDidMount i have this axios call:

```
componentDidMount() {
  axios.get("https://api.imgflip.com/get_memes").then(res => {
    const allMemeImgs = res.data.data.memes;

    this.setState({ allMemeImgs });

    console.log(this.state.allMemeImgs[0]);
  });
}
```

in the initial state i have declared an empty array:

```
this.state ={
  allMemeImgs: []
}
```

Now if i console log inside the Axios get request i can see my state updated. But if i try to log outside they give me an error or an empty array. So it probably means that the state is not really updated with the api data. What i'm missing there?
thank you

Answer (score 1):

`setState` is asynchronous, if you want to see your changes you have to do.

```
componentDidMount() {
  axios.get("https://api.imgflip.com/get_memes").then(res => {
    const allMemeImgs = res.data.data.memes;

    this.setState({ allMemeImgs }, () => {
      console.log(this.state.allMemeImgs[0]);
    });
  });
}
```

You should use the `setState` callback to guarantee the changes in your state.

Learn more about `setState` [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/11527#issuecomment-360199710)

Answer (score 0):

When you call `axios.get`, it returns a `Promise`.

A `Promise` will not be resolved immediately. That is when `then` block's code is executed(after the promise is resolved).

Right now, the `console.log` after the `axios` is executed as soon as `axios.get` is called, **not when you have received the response**.

Here, you can set your state inside the `then` block - like:

```
axios
    .get(url)
    .then(response => {
        // here you get the response - it may take time for this code to be executed
        // set your state here
        console.log(response);
    }
// this will be executed as your code will not know to wait for the response
console.log(state.response); // you'll not get the response here as this is 
                             // executed before the promise has resolved.
```

There is a more concise version - `async/await`. It is worth all the effort if you can invest some time knowing how callbacks, promises and async/await work - in that order.